# Align and resize text to image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image and a string, and I want to align the text to the center of the image and resize it to scale with the image. I tried doing it but failed:

```py
txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod"

fontsize = 1  # starting font size
para = textwrap.wrap(txt, width=15)
im = Image.open('bg.jpeg')
MAX_W, MAX_H = im.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", fontsize)
# portion of image width you want text width to be
img_fraction = MAX_H / 1000

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", fontsize)

breakpoint = img_fraction * im.size[0]
jumpsize = 75
while True:
    if font.getsize(txt)[0] < breakpoint:
        fontsize += jumpsize
    else:
        jumpsize = jumpsize // 2
        fontsize -= jumpsize
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", fontsize)
    if jumpsize <= 1:
        break

# optionally de-increment to be sure it is less than criteria

current_h, pad =   MAX_W / 8, 10
for line in para:
    w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
    draw.text(((MAX_W - w) / 2, current_h), line, font=font)
    current_h += h + pad

im.save('test.png')
os.remove('bg.jpeg')
```

Comment: What is the problem/error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function to trim white spaces

```
def trim(im):
    bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, im.getpixel((0, 0)))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
    bbox = diff.getbbox()
    if bbox:
        return im.crop(bbox)
```

To resize an image

```
img=img.resize((yourwidth,yourheight),Image.ANTIALIAS))
```

if you reduce the font size of the text the problem will be solved

Comment: thats not whats wrong i cant scale the font to the size of the font correctly

Comment: Have u tried? It works well even It helps for me also

Comment: @MaxDev Yes If u trim the image then font size will be automatically aligned

Comment: ok ill try but i dont know how to implement it

Comment: im not very good at python

Comment: Just use that function like trim(imageobj)

Comment: this only trims the image what i want to do is scale the text to image size

Comment: you mean resize?

Comment: yeah i generated the text and i aglined it to the middle but i cant scale it correctly

Comment: check resize function I have updated my solution

Comment: not the image the ext i want to scale the text to the image

Comment: could you please share screen shot and code?

Comment: code https://pastebin.com/p3JxR8K1

Comment: generated image https://i.imgur.com/7n5mOsS.jpg

Comment: text leaping out of image

Comment: font https://file.io/kxgWShvAwFYG

Comment: the problem is width..

Comment: The actual task is to write some text inside the image rgt?

Comment: So if you reduce the font size of the text the problem will be solved

Comment: All issues solved?